# Dynamic website scrapping: cannot fetch link generated after click on a list of elements already obtained

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, dynamic, fetch

I have a website in Portuguese with a database of all events venues in Rio de Janeiro. However, in order to get further information from each venue, I have to simulate a click on each header, which should open the venue's specific page, which I am trying to do using selenium with the help of Chat GPT (but it ran out of ideas as well SOS). From that page I want to fetch some information, with a focus on the location of each venue. My final objective is to plot a map with all of the venue locations pinpointed.

I know it can be confusing so here is an example:

- This is the website I am scrapping: https://visit.rio/congressos-eventos/encontre-o-espaco-ideal
- When you click on the first title: B&B Hotel Rio de Janeiro Copacabana...
- This page opens: https://visit.rio/a-cidade/hoteis/bb-hotel-rio-de-janeiro-copacabana-forte
- It contains the venue description, the address, contact information, and others, which I then wish to save to a CSV doc and generate a geo-referenced map. [but I am stuck before getting there, maybe there will be a continuation for this question]

The problem is that this link is not referenced on a  manner within the HTML. The header with the venue name is inside another div marked with a "flex" tag, so I cannot see the link on the Chrome inspector. Thus, I got to the conclusion that I have to simulate a click to collect the link afterwards, but it is not working.

**I first wrote a code that allowed me to get a list of all venues listed**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


# Set the path to the chromedriver executable
chrome_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

# Create a Service object with the chromedriver executable path
service = Service(executable_path=chrome_path)

# Create an instance of Chrome WebDriver with the Service object
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

# Load the page and wait for the search results to load
url = "https://visit.rio/congressos-eventos/encontre-o-espaco-ideal"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "q-app")))

# Find the list of venues and extract the names
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='col-12 text-h2']")
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
    

# Quit the browser
driver.quit()
```

I got the list and I expected I would be able to use the name of the venue and substitute it on the end of this link  https://visit.rio/a-cidade/hoteis/<venue_name>

But this was not possible as some of the results had some words cut, as the example I gave:

- name fetched and which shows on the main page: B&B Hotel Rio de Janeiro Copacabana...
- tarket link: https://visit.rio/a-cidade/hoteis/bb-hotel-rio-de-janeiro-copacabana-forte

So I tried to loop trough the list of elements, and simulate the click. But the code keeps on giving me (1) the wrong link [gives me the link of the original page] and (2) crashing on the second loop. I also tried many variations, none of them work properly and all of them give me similar errors.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1j-lfphAjEqTjvjgl-eWvWHqWy-Hb5Ui3?usp=sharing

PS: this might generate an error in google colab, but the selenium setup is working, what is not working is the final code to fetch the links

** One example, this code:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


# Set the path to the chromedriver executable
chrome_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

# Create a Service object with the chromedriver executable path
service = Service(executable_path=chrome_path)

# Create an instance of Chrome WebDriver with the Service object
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

# Load the page and wait for the search results to load
url = "https://visit.rio/congressos-eventos/encontre-o-espaco-ideal"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "q-app")))

# Find the list of venues and extract the names
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='col-12 text-h2']")
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
    element.click()
    
    # Wait for the new page to load and get the current URL
    wait.until(EC.url_changes)
    element_url = driver.current_url
    
    # Print the hotel URL
    print(element_url)
    
     # Go back to the previous page
    driver.back()
    
     # Wait for the previous page to load
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='col-12 text-h2']")))
    

# Quit the browser
driver.quit()
```

Generates this output/error:

```
B&B Hotel Rio de Janeiro Copacabana...
https://visit.rio/congressos-eventos/encontre-o-espaco-ideal
Belmond Copacabana Palace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ElementClickInterceptedException          Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/zq/ng01qfxs3638c4mk75_lbrhm0000gn/T/ipykernel_80095/4109051349.py in <module>
     30 for element in elements:
     31     print(element.text)
---> 32     element.click()
     33 
     34     # Wait for the new page to load and get the current URL

3 frames
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in click(self)
     91     def click(self) -> None:
     92         """Clicks the element."""
---> 93         self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
     94 
     95     def submit(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    401             params = {}
    402         params["id"] = self._id
--> 403         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    404 
    405     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None) -> WebElement:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    438         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    439         if response:
--> 440             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    441             response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))
    442             return response

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    243                 alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    244             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 245         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="col-12 text-h2" data-v-ab0c8938="">...</div> is not clickable at point (667, 410). Other element would receive the click: <div class="q-loading__backdrop"></div>
  (Session info: headless chrome=111.0.5563.64)
```

I think maybe I have to change the element I am fetching
I tried going for the parent div:

- `elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='q-card associados-card q-mb-xs']")`, but that just gave me a time out.
- Also tried with `class="q-loading__backdrop"`, as the error suggested, but that gave an empty output.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting the Network panel of the DevTools while clicking on one card, I found out that the click triggers a GET request to `https://api.rcvb.com.br/salesforce/dataac` which downloads the data of all cards.

[image]

So we can easily get everything by running

```
import requests
dictionary = requests.get(url = 'https://api.rcvb.com.br/salesforce/dataac').json()
```

which store data inside a `dict`. Actually, dictionary contains data abount 160 events, while on the website there are 46 events displayed, so we have to filter only the data we need. But first let's have a look at how data of an event is stored in the dictionary. For example by running `dictionary['records'][117]` we get data about "B&B Hotel Rio de Janeiro Copacabana Forte"

```
{'attributes': {'type': 'Account',
  'url': '/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Account/0011I000010bn6NQAQ'},
 'Name': 'B&B Hotel Rio de Janeiro Copacabana Forte',
 'Status__c': 'Mantenedor - Pagante',
 'Categoria__c': 'Hotéis',
 'Bairro__c': 'Copacabana',
 'E_mail__c': 'joao.araujo@hotelbb.com',
 'Logo__c': 'https://admin.rcvb.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/BB.jpg',
 'Website': 'https://www.hotel-bb.com/pt/br',
 'Aceita_Pet__c': True,
 'Acessibilidade__c': True,
 'Capacidade_da_Sala_Principal__c': 180,
 'Capacidade_de_todas_as_Salas__c': 350,
 'Capacidade_do_Estacionamento__c': 0,
 'Celular__c': None,
 'Op_es__c': None,
 'Tipo__c': None,
 'Type': None,
 'UH_total__c': 168,
 'Classifica_o_do_Hotel__c': '3*;Espaço para Eventos',
 'Description': None,
 'Dist_ncia_do_Aeroporto_Gale_o__c': 24.3,
 'Dist_ncia_do_Aeroporto_Santos_Dumont__c': 11.6,
 'Especialidade__c': None,
 'Facebook__c': None,
 'Foto__c': None,
 'NumberOfEmployees': None,
 'Imagem_Destaque__c': 'https://admin.rcvb.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/beb.jpg',
 'Imagem_Header__c': None,
 'Instagram__c': None,
 'Linkedin__c': None,
 'Industry': None,
 'Slide_1__c': 'https://admin.rcvb.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/BeB-2.jpg',
 'Slide_2__c': 'https://admin.rcvb.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/BeB.jpg',
 'Slide_3__c': 'https://admin.rcvb.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/BeB-3.jpg',
 'Subcategoria__c': None,
 'Phone': '+55 (21) 3505-5555',
 'Telefone_2__c': None,
 'Texto_Chamada__c': 'Com mais de 500 unidades distribuídas pela Europa, a rede B&B Hotels chegou ao Brasil em 2016.',
 'Texto_Chamada_Ingl_s__c': 'Com mais de 500 unidades distribuídas pela Europa, a rede B&B Hotels chegou ao Brasil em 2016.',
 'Texto_Mantenedor__c': 'Com mais de 650 unidades distribuídas pela Europa, a rede B&B Hotels chegou ao Brasil em 2017. De origem francesa, foi criada em 1990 e foca em oferecer modernidade e serviços efetivos.\r\nCom instalações econômicas de design e qualidade, os hotéis reúnem tudo e somente que é essencial aos hóspedes.',
 'Texto_Mantenedor_Ingl_s__c': 'With more than 650 unidades spread around Europe, the B&B Hotels brand came to Brasil in 2017. French by birth and created in 1990, its focus is on offering modernity and effective services.\r\nOur facilities combine design and quality with economic offers, delievering "only evrything" that is essential to our guests.',
 'Texto_para_o_Site__c': None,
 'Twitter__c': None,
 'WhatsApp__c': None,
 'YouTube__c': None,
 'N_mero_de_Audit_rios__c': 0,
 'Metragem_da_Sala_Principal__c': 120,
 'Metragem_de_todas_as_Salas__c': None,
 'N_mero_de_Cadeiras__c': None,
 'N_mero_de_Leitos__c': 340,
 'N_mero_de_Mesas__c': None,
 'N_mero_de_Salas__c': 3,
 'endereco': '{"city":"Rio de Janeiro","country":"Brasil","geocodeAccuracy":null,"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"postalCode":"22.080-040","state":"RJ","street":"Rua Francisco Otaviano, 38"}'}
```

Let's say that we want to extract these data `['Name','Categoria__c','Bairro__c','E_mail__c','Website','Phone','endereco','Texto_Mantenedor__c']`. We can do it with the following code:

```
# scrape the names of the events from the website
events = [div.text.replace('...','') for div in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class*=h2]')]

dictionary = requests.get(url = 'https://api.rcvb.com.br/salesforce/dataac').json()

data = {key:[] for key in ['Name','Categoria__c','Bairro__c','E_mail__c','Website','Phone','endereco','Texto_Mantenedor__c']}

for event in events:
    # find the index of the event inside the dictionary
    idx = [i for i,d in enumerate(dictionary['records']) if event in d['Name']]
    # get data associated to event
    event_data = dictionary['records'][idx[0]]
    name = event_data['Name']
    print('-'*len(name)+'\n'+name+'\n'+'-'*len(name))
    
    for key in data.keys():
        data[key] += [event_data[key]]
        print(key.upper(), '--->', event_data[key])
    
    print('\n')
```

Just to have a clear idea of what data is extracted, I added two lines of `print` which print data in the following format:

```
-----------------------------------------
B&B Hotel Rio de Janeiro Copacabana Forte
-----------------------------------------
NAME ---> B&B Hotel Rio de Janeiro Copacabana Forte
CATEGORIA__C ---> Hotéis
BAIRRO__C ---> Copacabana
E_MAIL__C ---> joao.araujo@hotelbb.com
WEBSITE ---> https://www.hotel-bb.com/pt/br
PHONE ---> +55 (21) 3505-5555
ENDERECO ---> {"city":"Rio de Janeiro","country":"Brasil","geocodeAccuracy":null,"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"postalCode":"22.080-040","state":"RJ","street":"Rua Francisco Otaviano, 38"}
TEXTO_MANTENEDOR__C ---> Com mais de 650 unidades distribuídas pela Europa, a rede B&B Hotels chegou ao Brasil em 2017. De origem francesa, foi criada em 1990 e foca em oferecer modernidade e serviços efetivos.
Com instalações econômicas de design e qualidade, os hotéis reúnem tudo e somente que é essencial aos hóspedes.
```

Finally, by running the following you can save data to a csv

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('events.csv', index=False)
```

and if you print `df` you get this

[image]